# Red Black Tree Null Pointer v Nil Leaf

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

Recently, I have been working on a red black tree in C++ and have already developed a functional insertion method, but when coding for deletion I have encountered a problem. Originally, I just had the left and right hold a value of NULL when created over having actual black NIL leaves and in the actual code for insertion I used if NULL or black when looking at nodes. However, within deletion, I need to get the parent of nodes which have the potential to be a NULL value instead of a NULL, which ultimately throws a segmentation fault. This leads to the question of if there is any way to implement delete and delete fixup for red black tree while using NULL pointers over NIL value leaves, as otherwise I will have to rework the entirety of the insertion as well. The code for the node class is as follows:

```
node :: node() { //constructor
  left = NULL;
  right = NULL;
  parent = NULL;
  color = 0;
  data = 0;
}

node :: ~node() {//destructor
  left = NULL;
  right = NULL;
}

void node :: setLeft(node* newLeft) {//sets left
  left = newLeft;
}

void node :: setRight(node* newRight) {//sets right
  right = newRight;
}

void node :: setParent(node* newParent) {//sets parent
  parent = newParent;
}

node* node :: getLeft() {//gets left
  return left;
}

node* node :: getRight() {//gets right
  return right;
}

node* node :: getParent() {//gets parent
  return parent;
}

void node :: setData(int newdata) {//sets data
  data = newdata;
}

int node :: getData() {//gets data
  return data;
}

void node :: setCol(bool newcol) {//sets color
  color = newcol;
}

bool node :: getCol() {//returns color
  return color;
}
```

The deletion and deletion fixup functions are almost identical to the standard red black tree deletion pseudo code, but if I should post that as well, please alert me. Thanks!

Comment: "Where's the Beef?"  Where is the code that maintains the tree?  You've given us node code, but not tree code.  Correction:  need the class declaration for `node` also, since the types for `left` and `right` are not defined in your original post.

Comment: The only time the parent should be a null value (whether NULL or an instantiated nil node) is when the current node is the tree root. There is no other case where a node in the tree will have a null parent, if you do you've messed up your tree somewhere.  And yes it's possible to write a delete operation with NULL pointers for the leaf nodes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote it poorly. Rather, my issue isn't with null parents, but getting the parents of null leaves